# Local NSF file item marked as $KeepPrivate =1 after reading it by C# application

Tags: c#, lotus

I am working with Lotus Notes client. I have C# windows application which is going to read the data from local NSF file.

When I read the data from NSF items it get marked as

> $KeepPrivate =1

It does not allow the user to forward or copy the email from NSF file.

I am not doing any changes to NSF file. I am only creating session with file and reading values from it. But after this process if user want to forward the existing email from NSF Lotus Notes do not allow to do so.

[image]

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks;
Mayur

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a bug in a lotus notes library (dll) which has been used upon this operation.

`$KeepPrivate`is a system field, and if it is set to a documents and it's value is "1" then this document cannot be forwared nor printed and nor copied.

To overcome this issue, read and save `$KeepPrivate` field value of a document before processing it.

If before processing `$KeepPrivate` holds an empty string or is not present (what, in general, is the same) just set empty string value to this field in your code, when all operations with this document are done.